# TypeError: exp.express is not a function. How to solve this problem when using express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express.js for the first time. after using npm installed express. I'm writing following code in Atom:

```
import * as exp from "express";
app = exp.express();
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("server start running");
});
```

because don't want to use require("express") for ES modules and have to use import...from..
after put node server.js it gives the following error at Hyper Terminal
[image]

so how to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you want `import express from "express";`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import express from "express";
app = express();
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("server start running");
});
```

Comment: The user explicit that he want to avoid require()

Answer (score 1):

Instead use `import * as ...`

You can simply do this:

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("server start running");
});
```

In this way you can import whole express module in a single import.